# How to organize the dependencies of a project

Tags: version-control, git, dependencies

I have a project built with Gradle, which contains libraries which can be used freely outside the main project, like this:

[image: Project structure]

The folders with a square at the bottom right are project modules.

I want to opensource this project (I mainly use Git and GitHub for tasks like this), but I have no idea how to organize it. Should I create separate repositories for each library (and if so, how can I link them to the main repository?), or should I put it all in one repo (I guess that's bad practice)?

The main criteria is that when `git clone repo_url` is run, it should recreate project structure one-to-one, so it can still be built with `./gradlew build`.

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6491#6491

Comment: @gnat, it may be opinion-based, but i suppose, that there is only one way to do it (best practice, if you want to). That's exactly the thing I'm looking for

Comment: recommended reading: [Why is asking a question on “best practice” a bad thing?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/142354/165773)

Comment: Actually, @gnat makes a good point that there *is* more than one way of doing it: You can probably handle the dependencies with gradle, which might be better (see edit to my answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create separate Git repositories for each library, publish them, then use [Git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) to link them to the main repository.

```
git submodule add submodule1_url directory1
git submodule add submodule2_url directory2
git commit -m "add submodules"
```

Working with submodules is a little more complex. After cloning the repo, you need to clone the submodules as well:

```
git clone repo_url
cd repo
git submodule init
git submodule update
./gradlew build
```

And voilà - you have a project with independent submodules.

---

You might also want to look at [gradle: Chapter 50. Dependency Management](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html). I haven't read that myself, but handling the dependencies outside of the SCM is often preferred, and as gnat was saying, you should take a look at the different options and decide for yourself.

Comment: well, according to the structure of my project I'll end up having three git repositories in one repo. Will Git handle it?

Comment: Oops, sorry, I haven't completely read the link you provided. Solved then.

Spoiler for those, who don't want to read git documentation: git will handle this.